# OnePage-scroll: how to keep the banner on top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to scroll page by page, having a top menu banner always in the top of the screen.

Here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/13fgdxgh/1/)

```js
$("section").onepage_scroll({
    sectionContainer: "article",
    loop: false
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0; margin: 0; }

header {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 100;
  background: yellow; opacity: .5;
  width: 100%; }

section {
  background: beige;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%; width: 100%; }

article {
  position: absolute;
  display: table-row;
  background: brown;
  height: 100%; width: 100%; }

article > div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table;
  text-align: center; }

article > div div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; }

article > div:first-of-type { background: red; }
article > div:last-of-type { background: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<link href="http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage-scroll.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/jquery.onepage-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>this is the top banner</header>
<section>
    <article>
        <div>
            <div>1 this is the first cell</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>this is the second</div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div>
            <div>2 this is the first cell</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>this is the second</div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div>
            <div>3 this is the first cell</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>this is the second</div>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

I need to display the FULL cell in the remaining space out of the banner. The cell should not overflow to the bottom (I should see the blue border at the bottom)

PS.

Setting the margin-top to the section gives this result when scrolling:

[image]

that is not good, as I need to see the full "cell" till the bottom on the page...

I need the result like this:

[image]

**BUT** will cell fully in the page (in the picture the bottom part of cell overflows the bottom of the page - e don't see the bottom blue border)!

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand, but if you put a margin-top of 50px (height of top banner) to the section (onepage-wrapper), it'll start 50px under the top..

Comment: Do you mean that you want the first cell and second cell to not overlap with the banner?

Comment: Your description is bad... but if i understand the title correctly, try to change header {position: fixed;}, not position: absolute;

Comment: thanks to all ... see my updated OP (PS).

Comment: try section {height: calc(100% - 50px);}

Comment: @tofarr: yes you are right: see the last image in the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following two CSS rules to the `section` which might serve your purpose:

```
<section style=" height: calc(100% - 50px); top:50px;" > <!-- ... -->
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/ka3wvq3c/).

***Note:*** *Adding the rules to the CSS stylesheet is somehow being overridden by the plugin your making use of.*

Comment: this is not so bad... even if there a part of the cell that scrolls under the banner...and the style is a little "hard-coded" (banner height-dependent)

Comment: I however would like to keep the HTML clean... setting in CSS `height: calc(100% - 50px) !important;` does not seem to work...

Comment: Yeah I know @Serge, but for what reason, it might be due to `.onepage_scroll` that you're using. Check if it has to say something about it in its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
section.onepage-wrapper {
     margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Remember to adjust the value when changing the height of the header. You can do that with jQuery, too:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( "section.onepager-wrapper" ).css({ "margin-top": $( "header" ).height() + "px" });
});
```

Comment: reduce the height of the cell, too, then u'll see the whole cell.